# Let's get critical: Jan 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Computational Science Stack Exchange](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Efficient computation of the matrix square root inverse](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10375/efficient-computation-of-the-matrix-square-root-inverse)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Hash in set probability?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10326/hash-in-set-probability)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can one outperform Cramer's rule for the inversion of a 3 by 3 matrix](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10383/can-one-outperform-cramers-rule-for-the-inversion-of-a-3-by-3-matrix)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Slow convergence of Newton's method for finite elements](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10184/slow-convergence-of-newtons-method-for-finite-elements)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is there congruent transform implementation for dense symmetric matrix in Eigen(C++)?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10386/is-there-congruent-transform-implementation-for-dense-symmetric-matrix-in-eigen)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Solve chemical formula (number of molecules in reaction)](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10289/solve-chemical-formula-number-of-molecules-in-reaction)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Methods to solve this equation on finite fields?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10367/methods-to-solve-this-equation-on-finite-fields)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Partial derivatives of a 3D array in Matlab](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10260/partial-derivatives-of-a-3d-array-in-matlab)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Finite element discretization of Reaction-diffusion problem with Dirac source term](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10166/finite-element-discretization-of-reaction-diffusion-problem-with-dirac-source-te)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Best place to start learning Stereophotogrammetry](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10295/best-place-to-start-learning-stereophotogrammetry)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

Answer (score 1):

As in the last site self-evaluation, I was struck by the high quality of answers, but this time around impressed as well by the breadth of questions being handled.  Based on this sample, at any rate, I'd give the Community a pat on the back for being inclusive and responsive.